# Surprised by performance of shared_ptr copy vs. shared_ptr::get()

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have a class member that is a vector of `std::shared_ptr`s to other objects, however I'm not really using the `shared_ptr`s to express shared ownership; I just need them because I want to use `std::weak_ptr` as an easy way to check if an object in the vector still exists.

Since I don't really need or want shared ownership, I was considering returning a vector of raw pointers to these objects from the accessor function, which I thought would be faster than copying the `shared_ptr`s.  Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Owner {

    //Constructor: populate the member vector with 50 shared_ptrs to doubles
    Owner() {
        for (int i = 0; i != 50; ++i)
            numbers.push_back(make_shared<double>(i));
    {}

    //Member vector of shared pointers
    vector<shared_ptr<double>> numbers;

    //Accesor function that returns a copy of the vector
    vector<shared_ptr<double>> GetSharedPtrs() {
        return numbers;
    }

    //Accesor function that returns the raw pointers from the vector
    vector<double*> GetRawPtrs() {
        vector<double*> ret;
        for (const auto& num : numbers)
            ret.push_back(num.get());
        return ret;
    }
};
```

I was surprised to find that the two methods are nearly identical in speed, based on the following test (MSVC 2013, default release mode optimization level):

```
int main() {

    Owner own;

    vector<shared_ptr<double>> shared;
    vector<double*> raw;

    chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start, stop;

    for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {

        start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (int j = 0; j != 10000; ++j)
            shared = own.GetSharedPtrs();
        stop = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        cout << "Shared pointers: \t" << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start).count() << " ms" << endl;

        start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (int j = 0; j != 10000; ++j)
            raw = own.GetRawPtrs();
        stop = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        cout << "Raw pointers: \t\t" << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start).count() << " ms" << endl;

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In all 10 iterations, the execution time for each accessor method was about 15 ms.  My intuition was that copying a `shared_ptr` would be more expensive than calling its `get()` method, however this seems not to be true.  Was my intuition wrong, or is my test method flawed?

Comment: The cost of copying the shared pointers and adjusting reference counts is probably dwarfed by the cost of allocating the memory for the vector.

Comment: I don't think you really thought that though. That's a vector of 50 shared_ptr's all right, but they are all to the same double. Also, try `reserve` upfront in your raw pointer case.

Comment: "Default release mode optimization level" It's hard to tell just from that what the generated assembly is. There's where the answer lies.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley The real problem would have been the atomic operations needed to copy/destroy shared pointers.

Comment: " Was my intuition wrong, or is my test method flawed?" you didn't use a profiler, that is what is wrong

Comment: @YamMarcovic, it's -O2.

Comment: @Carlton I meant the question was what assembly the compiler generated. It could have done many things to render this discussion moot. Maybe post that?

Comment: I reserved space for the return vector in `Owner::GetRawPtrs` and it makes a big difference (raw pointer method is now one-fifth the time of the shared_ptr version).  I would not have expected that.

Comment: That shouldn't be very surprising. In the first case you're copy constructing a `vector`, so the final size is known and a single memory allocation is performed. In the second case you `push_back` individual elements, so in the absence of `reserve`, the `vector` must go through several reallocations to reach size 50 (MSVC uses a growth factor of 1.5, so it'll take about 10 reallocations)

Comment: `numbers(50, shared_ptr<double>(new double))` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, I realize that now (based on T.C.'s comment).  I will update my question.